# Create a combination ID number from a set of factors in R

Tags: r

can anyone help me out in computing a new variable that will number a distinct combination from some factors?

Assuming there are 4 within subject factors (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) with 8 repetitions of each combination for any of 10 subjects, this is how my data could look like to represent it's actual structure:

```
library(AlgDesign) #for generating a factorial design)
df <-gen.factorial(c(2,2,2,2,8,10), factors = "all", 
                      varNames = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "replication", "Subject"))
> head(df)
  A B C D replication Subject
1 1 1 1 1           1       1
2 2 1 1 1           1       1
3 1 2 1 1           1       1
4 2 2 1 1           1       1
5 1 1 2 1           1       1
6 2 1 2 1           1       1
> tail(df)
     A B C D replication Subject
1275 1 2 1 2           8      10
1276 2 2 1 2           8      10
1277 1 1 2 2           8      10
1278 2 1 2 2           8      10
1279 1 2 2 2           8      10
1280 2 2 2 2           8      10
```

In this example `replication` was simply generated in order to force 8 reps but it doesnt "code" the combintation itself.

My original data has only variables `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `Subject` and I'd like to **compute**  `replication` in a way that it has distinct values 
**but** for each combination of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(AlgDesign) 
library(dplyr)

df <-gen.factorial(c(2,2,2,2,8,10), factors = "all", 
                   varNames = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "replication", "Subject"))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%                                             # for each row
  mutate(factors = paste0(c(A,B,C,D), collapse = "_")) %>%  # create a combination of your factors
  ungroup() %>%                                             # forget the row grouping
  mutate(replication_upd = as.numeric(factor(factors)))     # create a number based on the combination you have

# # A tibble: 1,280 x 8
#   A     B     C     D     replication Subject factors replication_upd
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>       <fct>   <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 1     1     1     1     1           1       1_1_1_1               1
# 2 2     1     1     1     1           1       2_1_1_1               9
# 3 1     2     1     1     1           1       1_2_1_1               5
# 4 2     2     1     1     1           1       2_2_1_1              13
# 5 1     1     2     1     1           1       1_1_2_1               3
# 6 2     1     2     1     1           1       2_1_2_1              11
# 7 1     2     2     1     1           1       1_2_2_1               7
# 8 2     2     2     1     1           1       2_2_2_1              15
# 9 1     1     1     2     1           1       1_1_1_2               2
#10 2     1     1     2     1           1       2_1_1_2              10
# # ... with 1,270 more rows
```

You can remove any unnecessary variables. I left them there so you can see how the process works.

Another option is this

```
# create a look up table based on unique combinations and assign them a number
df %>% distinct(A,B,C,D) %>% mutate(replication_upd = row_number()) -> look_up

# join back to original dataset
df %>% inner_join(look_up, by=c("A","B","C","D")) %>% tbl_df()

# # A tibble: 1,280 x 7
#   A     B     C     D     replication Subject replication_upd
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>       <fct>             <int>
# 1 1     1     1     1     1           1                     1
# 2 2     1     1     1     1           1                     2
# 3 1     2     1     1     1           1                     3
# 4 2     2     1     1     1           1                     4
# 5 1     1     2     1     1           1                     5
# 6 2     1     2     1     1           1                     6
# 7 1     2     2     1     1           1                     7
# 8 2     2     2     1     1           1                     8
# 9 1     1     1     2     1           1                     9
# 10 2     1     1     2     1           1                    10
# # ... with 1,270 more rows
```

Note that the first approach picks the numbers based on the new variable we create (i.e. orders A,B,C,D), and the second approach uses the initial order of you dataset to pick the number for each unique combination.